# getting rid of colons in URL using Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a URL which contains something like this...

http://www.example.com/stuff/http://www.foobar.com

I want this passed to index.php/stuff/http://www.foobar.com

I can parse it from there. If I don't have the colon in the URL, it works fine. Problem is... Apache seems to choke on the colon ":" character and it leads to a Forbidden error; and I can't just "remove" the colon as it comes from somewhere else.

I'm running Apache on Windows if it makes a difference.

Help required! Thanking you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue specific to Apache on Windows, colons are disallowed for security reasons and unfortunately Apache catches this and serves a 403 Forbidden before you can do any rewriting.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether it's Apache doing the choking - it might be the browser having trouble *parsing* the URL in the first place.

That is an invalid URL - the second address part should be URL encoded:

```
http://www.example.com/stuff/http%3a%2f%2fwww.foobar.com
```

if at all possible, you should change the URL structure accordingly.

Comment: I can't rewrite the URL using url-encoded text... I am getting the URL passed in from the outside, which is why I need Apache to translate it into something useful. The browser is not having a problem with it -- it's hitting the web server fine but Apache is trying to translate into an invalid directory name (I believe) which is what is leading to the Forbidden error.

Comment: @Momo fair enough. In that case, what RewriteRules are you using?