# htaccess colons used url http://localhost/1:1

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a problem with the colons used in url

this my url

http://localhost/1:1

this my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*):(.*) index.php/$1:$2
```

this error show
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /1:1 on this server.

Comment: What parameter you want to pass to index.php? Is it eg: `index.php?id=$1` something like that please confirm once.

Comment: 1:1 or 1:1/setting/2:1

Comment: Your parameter should be in key value pair(kind of) form. Means your parameter passed should have name before it, eg: `index.php?id=ABC&name=singh` here parameter names are id AND name, like this form please do mention once

Comment: I understand exactly, but my problem is that because the colon url used , I want to ignore the character of the colon and not make a mistake.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45582603/1427878